# In cloud code seems impossible to use Parse.Config.get() with express is it correct?

Tags: express, parse-platform

Is there any way to use Parse.Config.get() inside an expressjs app hosted in cloud code?

Looks very easy to use Parse.Object and Parse.User but with Parse.Config.get() the code is not deployed using "parse deploy"

We manage to use it adding the jssdk in html and using "frontend js" but haven't find any way to use in directly in express controllers.

Thanks

Comment: same issue here, did you find a better workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be related with some kind of permissions issues...

```
var Parse = require('parse-cloud-express').Parse;
var Util = require('util')

Parse.Cloud.define("currentConfig", function(request, response) {
  console.log('Ran currentConfig cloud function.');
  // why do I have to do this?
  Parse.initialize(xxx, yyy);
  Parse.Config.get().then(function(config) { 
    // never called
    // ...
    console.log(config.get('xxx'))
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(Util.inspect(error))
  });
});
```

Output

```
Ran currentConfig cloud function.
{ code: undefined, message: 'unauthorized' }
```

Edited code which work for me:

```
var Parse = require('parse-cloud-express').Parse;
var Util = require('util')

Parse.initialize("appId", "restApiKey", "masterKey");

Parse.Cloud.define("currentConfig", function(request, response) {
  console.log('Ran currentConfig cloud function.');
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  Parse.Config.get().then(function(config) { 
    // never called
    // ...
    console.log(config.get('xxx'))
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(Util.inspect(error))
  });
});
```

EDIT: Add solution :)